# In excel how to count the occurrence of each value in one column and group it by values in another column

Tags: excel, vba

I need to count the occurrence of each value in one column and group it by values in another.  How would I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following SUMPRODUCT will work:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$6=H$1)*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($G2,$B$2:$B$6))))
```

[image]

Comment: I always forget SUMPRODUCT is such an elegant solution compared to COUNT array formulas and DCOUNT style formulas...

Comment: above solution works on this particular example but I am not able to implement, as the search returns always returns false. Is there any other solution that I can try ?

Comment: Not with out seeing you actual data,  You may want to check you data and lookups for nonprintable character like spaces and returns.  Look at the Provider column in particular.

Comment: Please ignore my comment, I was making a dump mistake selecting the cell. It works perfect and I validate it too. Thanks the time